# IOS - Problems after retrieving data from a one-to-many relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

Im using Parse.com to store my data. This is the code I am using to retrieve my class data.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserSettings"];
[query whereKey:@"belongsToUser" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@",error, [error userInfo]);
    }
    else{
        //can't figure out how to extract the data from the objects NSArray that it was stored into above
    }
}];
```

So when this data is retrieved, it is stored in the objects NSArray. There are 3 pieces of data in that objects array that I need to populate into 3 separate textfields.

I know that data is there because if I NSLog the objects array I can see the data. This is the NSLog code.

```
NSLog( @"%@", objects);
```

and it returns this

```
"<UserSettings:2w12ebzirw:(null)> {
\n    belongsToUser = \"<PFUser:KttMAy9Sk3>\";
\n    companyAddress = \"1234 W. Peoria\";
\n    companyCity = Peoria;
\n    companyName = \"Adrian LLC\";\n}"
```

So the data is there. I need the companyAddress, companyCity, and companyName. I would like to be able to use the objectForKey option so I can give it the key "companyAddress" and get back "1234 W. Peoria". But NSArray doesn't have the objectForKey option. Even if I try to use objectAtIndex I get an error. This is my objectAtIndex code

```
NSLog( @"%@", [objects objectAtIndex:1]);
```

and this is the error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I retrieve my data and assign it to separate textfields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your replies rmaddy and Dima.  I did find out the issue.  I do realize that arrays are 0 based and when I called for the 0 index I was getting the same error.

My problem was I didn't realize that when parse was returning my query, it was returning it as a PFObject (which is like another array) and that PFObject was placed in the first index of my NSArray, objects.  So it was basically an array within the first index of another array.  What I had to do was assign the first index of my objects NSArray to a new NSArray (I assigned it to an NSDictionary).

```
NSDictionary *settings = [objects lastIndex];
```

Then I was able to use/call the data from the NSDictionary as you would normally.

Answer (score 0):

The error is actually pretty clear. You logged the output of your `NSArray` and there is only one element in it. Then you try to grab the second element, which doesn't exist.

`[objects objectAtIndex:0]` should work fine, or better yet, use subscripting and you can just do `objects[0]`.

Comment: Perhaps the OP doesn't realize that array indexes are 0-based.

Comment: Yeah this is possible. So OP, if that is indeed the case.. just remember that arrays are 0 based (or at least in most languages). :)